# include function definitions present in .c files in main

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor

I had to write few functions which are very long. So, I decided to put them in different files and link them to main.. so that it works as if I wrote function definitions after `main()`.

How do I do it..

Answer (score 4):

In a .h file you put your prototype

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H
void hello(void);
#endif
```

In a seperate .c file you implement your function such as hello.c

```
#include "myheader.h"
void hello()
{
    printf("Testing function from other file\n");
}
```

then in main you do

```
#include "myheader.h"

int main()
{
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

make sure you compile hello.c into hello.o before linking the files or it will tell you that it can't resolve the reference to hello.

Comment: You are using the wrong terminology. A prototype would be `void hello(void);`. What you are giving is just a declaration, and that declaration allows `hello` to be called with any number and type of argument.

Comment: @Jens, I was trying to keep it simple for him since he doesn't seem to understand the basics of it. Will edit in the correct one if you feel that it would make more sense.

Comment: @Jens in hindsight I should have done that to begin with but in my experience when I show that to some people they are more confused than anything else (as it's not typical of other languages).

Answer (score 0):

Find create a header file that has a file ending of .h .
Lets say this header file is named blah.h.

The general structure of this header will be

```
#ifndef BLAH_H_INCLUDED
#define BLAH_H_INCLUDED

//code

#endif // BLAH_H_INCLUDED
```

Those are header guards, to prevent multiple inclusions.
Inside the code you will still your function declarations.

For example,   `void function(int blah);` would be a valid function declaration.

This file is then included at the top of all of your files that uses or defines the functions declared, `#include "blah.h"`

Then you can define your functions in the other files, and when you link them together the program will work.